# internal string caching in R

Tags: r, data.table, internals

This question is stemming from the following `data.table` bug report - [#4978](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=4978&group_id=240&atid=975), but I'm going to use a `data.frame` example to illustrate that this is not a `data.table` specific issue:

Consider the following:

```
df = data.frame(a = 1, hø = 1)

identical(names(df), c("a", "hø"))
#[1] TRUE

.Internal(inspect(names(df)))
#@0x0000000007b27458 16 STRSXP g0c2 [NAM(2)] (len=2, tl=0)
#  @0x000000000ee604c0 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "a"
#  @0x0000000007cfa910 09 CHARSXP g0c1 [gp=0x21] [cached] "hø"

.Internal(inspect(c("a", "hø")))
#@0x0000000007b274c8 16 STRSXP g0c2 [] (len=2, tl=0)
#  @0x000000000ee604c0 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "a"
#  @0x0000000007cfa970 09 CHARSXP g0c1 [gp=0x24,ATT] [latin1] [cached] "hø"
```

Notice, that even though `identical` thinks the two are identical, the underlying string cache stores the "hø" in two different places, while storing the "a" in one. What is happening? Is this an R string-caching bug?

And the reason this matters is that `%chin%` fails here (because of the above discrepancy):

```
library(data.table)
"a" %chin% names(df)
#[1] TRUE
"hø" %chin% names(df)
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: this feels like a problem for the `data.table` package maintainer. While I am curious to know the answer too, I doubt that this counts as an R bug because R (presumably) doesn't make any guarantees to the user about how/where it stores strings ... presumably it's not an accident that you used `"hø"` as your example -- does this happen repeatably if and only if you consider non-ASCII characters?

Comment: +1. I get the expected answer after `names(df)[2] <- "hø"; "hø" %chin% names(df)`. Maybe it's got something to do with how `data.frame` treats names...

Comment: @BenBolker yep, only for those

Comment: @eddi, this (`%chin%` and `chmatch` behaviour) has been fixed in [1.8.11 (commit 976)](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php?view=rev&root=datatable&revision=976).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`"hø"` is being marked as being in UTF-8 encoding when printed direct to the console. You can force it to be native using `enc2native` and this problem disappears, however I am still working out why this is...

```
Encoding("hø")
# [1] "UTF-8"

.Internal( inspect( c( "a" , enc2native("hø") ) ) )
#@1081d60a0 16 STRSXP g0c2 [] (len=2, tl=0)
#  @100af87d8 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "a"
#  @1081e3a08 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x21] [cached] "hø"

enc2native("hø") %chin% names(df)
#[1] TRUE
```

On the `Encoding` help page there is a lot of relevant info, I this would be relevant:

> There are other ways for character strings to acquire a declared
>   encoding apart from explicitly setting it (and these have changed as R
>   has evolved). Functions scan, read.table, readLines, and parse have an
>   encoding argument that is used to declare encodings, iconv declares
>   encodings from its from argument, and console input in suitable
>   locales is also declared. intToUtf8 declares its output as "UTF-8",
>   and output text connections (see textConnection) are marked if running
>   in a suitable locale. Under some circumstances (see its help page)
>   source(encoding=) will mark encodings of character strings it outputs.

#### Update

Seems to me that anything in the basic ASCII character (character codes 0-127) set gets an `"unknown"` encoding, and any characters outside of this get set to `"UTF-8"` by default, including from the extended ASCII codes (character codes 128-255).

Comment: thanks! this definitely solves the problem as far as the bug report goes, but I still don't understand what's happening :)

Comment: @eddi me neither. I'm not sure why it should encode ASCII characters as UTF-8, but then I don't know enough about encodings - they really confuse me!